# JS Library not loading on Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

I have installed list.js within my application on laravel. I am trying to follow the best practice while working on laravel but I am a bit new on it!

I did it trough `npm install list.js` & then run `npm run dev` on my console

This process was successful. Then I have added into my app.js the line `require('list.js');`

This also works and the file is getting compiled properly.

But now when I start the library:

```
var options = {
    valueNames: [ 'list-rest-name', 'list-cuisine' ]
};

var userList = new List('wrap-rest-list', options);
```

I get:

```
app.js:13917 Uncaught ReferenceError: List is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:13917)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:13881)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
    at app.js:63
    at app.js:66
```

Like my application is not loading the library at all.

Any idea why?

I am loading my app.js on the head of my application!

Comment: Can you paste how are your loading your `app.js`? maybe you have a `defer` attribute in it.

Comment: yes I have it! :S I am loading all with defer

Comment: maybe you can try removing it, and see if your code is working.

Comment: no, still does not work! The only way I can make it work is placing the library on the public folder and call it on the blade itself (not even on the header blade)... I can do that but why would I use npm then :(

Answer (score -1):

well I found the problem so I will leave the answer in case someone find is useful

So after install trough `npm` you have to go to your `app.js` located at `resources/js` and add the require but in the following way: `var List = require('list.js');`

(you must create the variable in order to let your app recognize it)